# Tooltip issue with gvis bubble chart in r

Tags: r, tooltip, googlevis

I am trying to modify the tooltip for gvisBubbleChart using the documentation given at - 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/vignettes/Using_Roles_via_googleVis.html

My code is

`temp <- data.frame(id = c("a","b","c","d","e"), x = c(1,2,3,4,5), y = c(1,2,3,4,5), y.html.tooltip = c("a","b","c","d","e"))`

`plot(gvisBubbleChart(data = temp, idvar = "id", xvar = "x", yvar = c("y", "y.html.tooltip")))`

The following error is showing up -

`Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : arguments imply differing number of rows: 5, 0`

I have modified tooltips using the above method for other chart types provided by googleVis package. But this does not seem to work for bubble charts. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
plot(gvisBubbleChart(data = temp, idvar = "id", xvar = "x", yvar = c("y")))
```

works fine for me.